# Show math operation syntax not result

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `var x= 12/2` and i want to view it like this `12/2` and not `6`. When I do `x.toString()` or `String(x)` i get the result as string. Is there a way to get the operation as it is and not the result when the original value is not string?

Comment: During evaluation, 12/2 becomes 6. There's no 12/2 anywhere in memory other than the source code itself. If you need to represent fractions, I suggest you create a Fraction class.

Comment: Could you define your variable as "12/2" and use eval to get the value? That way, you would have access to the original expression.

Comment: most answers look alikebut persue different approach..thanks to all for sharp feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you actually execute a statement like:

```
var x = 12 / 2;
```

you actually *lose* information. The information lost is that which was used to create the result of the expression, which is the numerator and denominator. All you end us with is the result `6`.

There is no way to get from that statement back to the original form since it's just as likely to be `24/4` or `594/99`.

If you want to *keep* that information, you will need to store the value in such a way that it's not lost, such as creating a structure/class containing the numerator and denominator (i.e., a rational).

That way, you can get at those values, as well as calculating the result any time you need it.

There are numerous rational libraries floating around but you probably want to look for one that gives you the option of not normalising the numbers, such as turning `7/21` into `1/3`.

Or you could choose something incredibly simple, such as:

```
"use strict";

class Rational {
    constructor(pnum, pden) {
        this.num = pnum;
        this.den = pden;
    }
    expr() {
        return "(" + this.num + "/" + this.den + ")";
    }
    result() {
        if (this.den === 0) {
            if (this.num === 0) {
                return "undefined";
            }
            return "infinite";
        }
        return this.num / this.den;
    }
}

var ratnum = new Rational(6, 4);
console.log(ratnum.expr());
console.log(ratnum.result());
```

That's using the ES6 class-based syntactic sugar. If you prefer the older style, it can also be done thus:

```
function Rational(pnum, pden) {
    this.num = pnum;
    this.den = pden;
};
Rational.prototype = {
    expr: function() {
        return "(" + this.num + "/" + this.den + ")";
    },
    result: function() {
        if (this.den === 0) {
            if (this.num === 0) {
                return "undefined";
            }
            return "infinite";
        }
        return this.num / this.den;
    }
};

var ratnum = new Rational(6, 4);
console.log(ratnum.expr());
console.log(ratnum.result());
```

In both those cases, you'll see the output in the two different ways:

```
(6/4)
1.5
```

Comment: JS supports Java now?

Comment: @djechlin, not sure I understand the comment, this *is* JS. Tested successfully both on JSFiddle (albeit with `alert` rather than `console.log` since I can't figure out where the console is in JSFiddle's new site) and as a Node.js script.

Comment: This is an ES6 class. Looks a lot like Java syntax.

Comment: @TedA. But, to be clear, it is just syntactic trickery. JavaScript actually is a classless language (still in ES6). It's just a keyword/pattern to make you "feel" like you are in Java.

Comment: Absolutely true. Other than not being hoisted (tricky gotcha!) it's still a function under the covers.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get the operation as it is and not the result when the original value is not string?

No, because `12/2` is an expression that gets evaluated before the assignment happens. You can't "reverse engineer" the original expression from the result.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you call `var x = 12/2`, the variable `x` is set to the value 6.

If you want to be able to show both '12/2' and the computed value, you could store your expression as a string, and use `eval()` (be very careful using this) to get the computed value of the expression.

But you could do:

```
var x = '12/2';
console.log(x); >> Outputs '12/2'
console.log(eval(x)); >> outputs 6
```

As many others have said, eval() should never be used on a string that didn't come directly from you, as it can open your site to security vulnerabilities.

From MDN:

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways to which the similar Function is not susceptible.
>
> eval() is also generally slower than the alternatives, since it has to invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized by modern JS engines.
>
> There are safer (and faster!) alternatives to eval() for common use-cases.

Comment: While you could do this, it's a terrible idea. I'm yet to find a real world example where the use if `eval()` is justified.

Comment: eval does kind of prove the point here but I really don't like just throwing the word "caution" out as a substitute for actually showing cauion. IMO *you* should read up on it if you're going to post an answer using it.

Answer (score 1):

When you write an expression like:

```
 var x = 12 / 2;
```

**You are writing an expression that needs to be *evaluated*.** So, that's what the JS engine does.

There is one way that I can think of, and frankly I hesitate to tell you it because it is WIDELY considered to be one of the worst things you can do in JS (more to follow):

```js
      var expression = "12 / 2";

      var result = eval(expression);

      alert(expression + " produces " + result);
```

> Now, this may do what you want, but `eval()` is known to be **EVIL** because
>   it will evaluate ANY string that you pass to it and that can open up
>   security holes in an application. In addition, `eval()` brings any
>   declarations it finds into the current scope, which can wipe out
>   variables you were counting on.

**Does this do what you ask? Yes. Should you do it? No!**

Comment: `eval` is only "evil" if you actually evaluate unverified input. There is nothing wrong with `eval` itself. Sure, there are other reasons to avoid it, but it doesn't have to be avoided at all cost.

Comment: @FelixKling Actually, it should be avoided at all costs. Security issues + scope problems are not worth what you can accomplish with other coding techniques.  There is really never a valid reason to use it.

Comment: *"There is really never a valid reason to use it."* Except you want to actually evaluate JavaScript expressions maybe? Or do you advice to build your own JavaScript interpreter instead?

Comment: You're allowed to run it to see what it does or to teach yourself something about how the language works. That's the use case we're on at the moment. I would never sign off on any use of it in production no matter how "safe" though.

Comment: @FelixKling I agree that if there were no other way to do what you need, there could be a use case for it, but, there really is no expression that can't be evaluated in other ways besides using `eval()`.  (http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html)

Comment: I've personally never needed reflection in my own coding though... I'd be curious whether pastebin.com or codeacademy.com, or possibly the angularjs or Closure libraries, need to use `eval` to wire their frameworks together or run user code. As I've never written such a technology I won't claim you should "never" use `eval`. I haven't needed to and I wouldn't on anything I work on.

Comment: @FelixKling Another way to put it is this: If a technique opens the doors to bugs and security risks and there are other techniques that accomplish your goal that do not open the doors to such risks, then the best-practice would be to not use the former approach. Such is the case with `eval()`.

Comment: @Scott, that's fine and normally I'd agree, but using `eval` with an expression you totally control is *not actually* a security risk.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not advocating the use of `eval`. But I don't think much of the "`eval` is evil" mantra. Every tool has its uses. `eval` is a very special tool with narrow use cases. I'd rather have others understand when/where to use this too (and teach about indirect `eval` calls for example)l. Evaluating dynamically generated JavaScript is definitely one of these cases.

Comment: Perhaps not, but there are still scope issues. AND, in the end can you really describe a situation where you MUST use eval() to solve your problem and there is no other way to get to your solution?  I would guess not, so that leads us back to 'Why use eval() when other, better, less bug prone, less security risky ways exist'?

Comment: @FelixKling Why not use JSON.parse for dynamically created JS? Again, can you name a use case that requires eval()?

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Indirect `eval` calls or using the `Function` constructor solve the scope issue. As for a usage example: I have a tool with a JavaScript text editor and I want to execute the code that visitors type in there.

Comment: @Scott: `JSON.parse` only parses JSON. It doesn't evaluate JavaScript.

Comment: "Eval is evil" is *exactly* like "don't use goto" or "only have one return point from a function" - you need to understand the *reason* behind the guideline. For the latter two, it's to avoid spaghetti code which means, provided you use them wisely, they're fine (and better than the alternative in certain cases). For `eval`, it's to avoid arbitrary code execution within the context of your program which means, provided you control the input to it, that's not a problem.

Comment: @paxdiablo I disagree. The reason we have best-practices is not to keep a developer from harming themselves. Development happens in a group process, with people of different skill levels and knowledge working together. We don't use goto because it makes the code harder to read and understand for "some" people on the team. We don't use eval because it opens up security holes and bugs when some people don't use them correctly. These elements are language "features", not language requirements. Both are examples of what to avoid (continued).

Comment: ...at all costs because they do harm to the development process as a whole. And, perhaps most importantly, they are not needed to solve any problem that comes up. For example, if you are relying on goto, then you probably need to restructure the flow of the code to a more manageable and understandable pattern. And, if you need eval(), you haven't thought through why you are evaluating what you are.

Comment: @FelixKling With JSON, I can package up JavaScript code (a function) into a property...effectively turning it into a method. Withe JSON.parse, I can unpack an object that allows me to execute that method.

Comment: I have worked with literally hundreds of various corporations and government entities and can tell you that nearly 100% of them do not allow eval() (or goto) in any production code. There is a reason for that.

Comment: Then we'll have to agree to disagree. I don't throw away useful features of *any* system just because there may be people who would use it unwisely. For example, I *know* (and can mitigate) the dangers of a chainsaw where people who don't know about kickback could probably take off one of their limbs. I'm not returning to using a handsaw because of that :-) Similarly, there are situations where eval/goto/etc can be used without danger and in a way that makes the code more readable or quicker to develop, etc. It's the knowing of how to use your tools that makes you an artisan.

Comment: But this is quickly becoming a "religious" discussion in which we're unlikely to convince each other so I'll leave it there.

Comment: @paxdiablo (As an aside...I just bought a new chainsaw today...LOL) But, interestingly, to your artisan point. Organizations don't want to hire artisan coders. They don't want a code-base that only one person can understand, maintain, scale and test. That's why we need to think with a group mentality. I bought my chainsaw for just me to use, not my children -- they get the hand saw.

Comment: @Scott, yes, I mentioned the chainsaw analogy for that very reason. The NSA told me you'd bought one so I wanted to be topical. Cheers :-)

Comment: Have a nice day!  :)

Comment: *"With JSON, I can package up JavaScript code (a function) into a property...effectively turning it into a method."* JSON only supports data, not code: http://json.org . Really not sure what you are talking about here, we don't have to prolong this discussion unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

**Do NOT do this:**

1. Assuming this JS runs in a `<script>` element
2. Use `currentScript` to get that element
3. Use `text` to get the source code
4. Somehow, parse it until you find your variable. In the following example I used regexp.
   Be aware JS is not a regular language, so can't be parsed properly by regexp.
5. Obtain the expression assigned to the variable.

```js
var x = 12 / 2;

var source = document.currentScript.text;
var expression = (source.match(/var x = (.+?);/) || [])[1];
document.write(expression);
```

Comment: While I happen to get the point, "Don't do this" *really* doesn't make for a clear answer. (Not my DV, I don't do that if I leave a constructive comment.)

Comment: @djechlin True, at first I thought the code was self-describing but then I realized it needed better explanation.

Comment: `currentScript` is not supported in IE. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)

Answer (score 1):

Your browser completely throws away `12/2` and just remembers `6`. You can see this in action: Type `12/2<enter>` into your console and that's what happens.

You need to *also* store 12/2. *Probably* by storing it as a string.

```
var stringVersion = '12/2';
var numberVersion = 12/2;
// The following are ways to get Javascript to convert the string to a number.
// They all come out to the value 12/2.
Number(stringVersion) === numberVersion; //true
+stringVersion === numberVersion; //true
eval(stringVersion) === numberVersion; //true
```

Normally `eval` leads to trouble (e.g. security attacks) but it's very illustrative here. Running `eval` on a *string* is like typing the string into the console and eval-uating it. So you can see in action how the text "12/2" converts to the number.

Comment: "You can see this in action: Type 12/2<enter> into your console and that's what happens" --- *technically* this does not prove anything. Just because REPL strictly evaluates an expression - does not mean the whole language is strictly evaluated. Example: haskell

Comment: Seems like a more complex version of what I already explained more clearly with 3 lines of code below.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Not really, for one, you didn't mention any healthy way to convert a string to a number. Secondly, two explanations isn't the end of the world.